# Handle Cancel button on Safari/Chrome for Open in App Store pop up

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-chrome, deep-linking

Is there a way to handle `Cancel` button on the **Open in App** pop up when I redirect from Safari/Chrome to AppStore?

The scenario is something like this: A user receives a message to download the app. It is a browser link. On that browser link check if it is an **android** or **ios**? If iOS redirect to `App Store` or otherwise.

This works seamlessly on android. But iOS on the other hand displays a pop-up to the user, weather to switch and open in another app.

Now my client requires me to handle the `Cancel` button.

So, could there be a way to handle this via JavaScript?

Code looks something like this:

```
if($rootScope.$device.Android()) {
    window.location = appConfig.PLAYSTORE_LINK;
    return;
}

if($rootScope.$device.iOS()) {
   window.location = appConfig.APPSTORE_LINK;
   return;
}
```

**P.S.:** Though, I believe it is an OS level pop-up. It might not be a possibility or a feasible solution to handle this pop-up.

[image: link]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: this is a user interface element controlled by Apple. You cannot programatically manipulate this alert.

Answer (score 0):

The popup is render blocking so adding a setTimeout with the action you want to set when the user clicks cancel should be fine.

If the user click open then they will be taken to the app store. If the user clicks cancel the setTimeout will handle the cancel action.

```
window.location.href = "{{$primary_redirect}}";

setTimeout(()=>{
  // action to take if the user cancels. 
}, 3000)
```

It's a hacky solution to Apples weird ways but it